# Email notification using java i can face error as Could not connect to SMTP host: RELAY.MY.COM, port: 25, response: 421

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struct

[image]This error is occurring occasionally and i couldn't find the root cause of this issue. 
plz help me out of this issue.

Comment: make sure your Transport instance is properly closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### SMTP Status Codes

> **4.2.1**
>
> The Mail transfer service is unavailable because of a transient event.
>   SMTP reply
>
> 421 can be caused by many things but generally indicates that the mail
>   server which returns this status code is currently unavailable but may
>   be available later.
>
> For example, the server administrator may have stopped the mail
>   service to troubleshoot a problem, or the mail server is right in the
>   middle of rebooting, or the mail server is currently processing too
>   many incoming messages or incoming requests, etc... Note : “Mail
>   Server” in this case can be any of the mail servers on the message’s
>   route – the sending server (your server), the ISP SMTP server, or the
>   recipient’s mail server.
>
> Clearly, if you repeatedly receive an SMTP status 421 then the problem
>   is no longer of a transient nature and you need to investigate or
>   inform the relevant network administrator, ISP tech support, or the
>   recipient.
>
> SMTP Response 421 can also be received as a result of your message
>   server sending an email where the total number of TO, CC, and BCC
>   users results in a number of simultaneous SMTP connections that is in
>   excess of the number of connections your ISP or SMTP service allows. A
>   typical error message for this situation would be : “421 Too many
>   concurrent SMTP connections from this IP address; please try again
>   later”. Typically, when this happens your server will have sent some
>   of the messages (note that for all servers, each email sent by a user
>   always gets broken down into individual separate emails to each of the
>   recipients in the TO, CC, and BC fields), and will automatically retry
>   a little later to send the remaining messages.

Source http://wiki.mattrude.com/SMTP_Status_Codes

Comment: Thanks for your clarification -Based on this exception i have analysed to find out the root cause of this exception.

in my application with in a minute,it generate more than 100 mails. so my SMTP server cannot able to send those mails.so this is what my assumption.

i want to know how to resolve this problem.

Comment: Many ISPs limit the rate at which you can send email. As an example see [Improved Email Rate Limiting](http://releases.cpanel.net/releases/11-32/improved-email-rate-limiting/): "We have added a “soft” limit to the maximum number of emails that can be delivered hourly. Once this limit is reached, no messages will be accepted for the account.".

I suggest you talk to the administrator of your SMTP server.

Comment: Not until you figure out **why** you are getting transient errors ... which is why I suggested you talk to the administrator of your SMTP server.